# Vue js loading js file in mounted() hook

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-loader

I have the following Vue component:

```html
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="main-container">
      <Header />
      <router-view/>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>


import './assets/js/popper.min.js';
// other imports
// ....
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components : {
    Header,
    Footer
  },
  mounted(){
    // this is syntax error
    import './assets/js/otherjsfile.js'
  }
}
</script>
```

As is clear from the code snippet, I want to have the `otherjsfile.js` loaded in `mounted()` hook. That script file has certain IIFEs which expects the html of the web page to be fully loaded.

So how do I invoke that js file in a lifecycle hook?

Answer (score 3):

This is the pattern I use. The example is importing a js file which contains an IIFY, which instantiates an object on `window`.

The only problem with this would occur if you want to use SSR, in which case you need Vue's `<ClientOnly>` component, see [Browser API Access Restrictions](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/using-vue.html)

```js
mounted() {
  import('../public/myLibrary.js').then(m => {
    // use my library here or call a method that uses it
  });
},
```

Note it also works with npm installed libraries, with the same path conventions i.e non-relative path indicates the library is under node_modules.

Answer (score -3):

I'm a little unsure of what your asking.  But if you are just trying to include an external js file in your page, you can just use the `script` tag in your template and not have to put anything in your `mounted` function, like this:

```html
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="main-container">
      <Header />
      <router-view/>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
    <script src="./assets/js/otherjsfile.js"></script>
  </div>
</template>

<script>


import './assets/js/popper.min.js';
// other imports
// ....
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components : {
    Header,
    Footer
  },
}
</script>
```

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.